# Compile error help and centering Title on userform

Tags: excel, vba

The below code gives me a compiling error. "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" The error seems to occur on the .Filters.Add
The .Add is highlighted in blue if that helps.

Also, how can I center the title text on a userform.

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()

'myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select a File.")

Dim fname As String
Dim fpath As String

fpath = ThisWorkbook.Path

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .InitialFileName = fpath
    .ButtonName = "Get File Name"
    .Title = "File Selection"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "*.xl", "*.xlsx", "*.xlsm", "*.xlb", "*.xlam", "*.xltx", "*.xltm", "*.xls", "*.xla", "*.xlt", "*.xlm", "*.xlw"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    If .Show = True Then
        fname = .SelectedItems(1)
        Me.TextBox1.Text = fname
    Else
        MsgBox "Operation Canceled"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think .Filters.Add "*.xl", "*.xlsx", "*.xlsm" should be .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xl", "*.xlsx", "*.xlsm"

Comment: @RADO close but not correct.*Filters.Add(Description As String, Extension As String, [Position])* So you set the description to "Excel" which is fine, your extension to ".xl" and position to ".xlsx", then you have a forth arguement. To have mulitiple extensions they are all in **one** string with **;** as seperator so `"*.xl; *.xlsx; *.xlsm"`

Answer (score 0):

The `Filter.Add` have three arguements. You have given 12 arguments. Change to `.Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xl; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlb; *.xlam; *.xltx; *.xltm; *.xls; *.xla; *.xlt; *.xlm; *.xlw"` and it should work fine.